# Ansible become_user error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, ansible, sudo

I have problem with ansible. I want to configure sudo from another user:

> hosts: testnodes
>
> become: yes
>
> become_user: nadya
>
> become_method: sudo

But when I execute playbook, I have an error:

> An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py",
>   line 119, in run
>       res = self._execute()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py",
>   line 490, in _execute
>       result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py",
>   line 33, in run
>       results = merge_hash(results, self._execute_module(tmp=tmp, task_vars=task_vars))   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/**init**.py",
>   line 617, in _execute_module
>       self._fixup_perms2(remote_files, remote_user)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/**init**.py",
>   line 394, in _fixup_perms2
>       ' see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user'.format(res['rc'],
>   res['stderr'])) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character u'\u2018' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> fatal: [192.168.3.99]: FAILED! => {
>       "failed": true, 
>       "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
>       "stdout": "" }

ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0

If I set `become_user: root` everything is ok.

On remote host /etc/sudo:

`ansible ALL=(nadya) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure, that I write words using Englishh keyboard. I don't copy this string: "become_user: nadya"

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in your traceback output:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/action/init.py", line 394, in _fixup_perms2
' see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user'.format(res['rc'], res['stderr']))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Which is basically about the fact that Python can't parse `res['rc']` or `res['stderr']`.
This means that remote system printed something non-ascii into stderr as error message.

As you said, you run Ansible 2.2.0.0, so you can check what this error is about [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/cdec853e37d2342346f54e51f4ec4bfbd2ee0031/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L392):

```
                raise AnsibleError('Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user'
                        ' (rc: {0}, err: {1}). For information on working around this,'
                        ' see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user'.format(res['rc'], res['stderr']))
```

To avoid the error, fix permissions or use workarounds from [provided](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user) link.

Comment: Thanks! After that I've install acl and everything is ok.